# Utility functions to instantiate instance of a CoffeeScript class that extends a pre-existing object

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript, prototype, javascript-objects

So I've been playing with prototypal inheritance in CoffeeScript, and in particular with how one can go about writing CoffeeScript classes that inherit from a particular object, rather than another class, similar to Crockford's object function. Essentially what I'd like to do is to write a class that can inherit from a particular object passed in to its constructor. Unfortunately, I believe this may be impossible without resort to `setPrototypeOf`, which, given the rather alarming warnings about it, I'd rather not do. Instead I am probably going to settle for a function that can do something similar. Below are two possibilities:

```
a = {foo: 1}

class Example
  constructor: (@bar) ->

extendObject = (parent, Class, args...) ->
  F = (anon...) -> Class.apply(@, anon)
  F:: = Object.create parent
  F::constructor = Class
  new F args...

extendObjectMaker = (parent, Class) ->
  F = (anon...) -> Class.apply(@, anon)
  F:: = Object.create parent
  F::constructor = Class
  F

maker = extendObjectMaker a, Example

test1 = extendObject a, Example, 2
test2 = new maker 2
```

Now, I greatly prefer the second approach, since essentially what it is returning is a new class, which you can then use regular constructor syntax with. There's just one problem: while objects created using `extendObject` correctly identify as `Example`s, objects created using the constructor returned by `extendObjectMaker` identify as `F`s, and are not instances of `Example`.

```
console.log test1 instanceof Example # True
console.log test2 instanceof Example # False
```

Given that these functions use almost exactly the same code, I'm having difficulty figuring out just why they're exhibiting different behavior. So, does anyone know why `test2` is not showing up as an `Example`, and what I need to change to make it do so?

Comment: Seems like you're not on the right website for this :)

Comment: Uh, why would that be?

Comment: Oh my, I'm so sorry! Stackoverflow on mobile has the color scheme of another stackexchange website!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the CoffeeScript source code: http://coffeescript.org/v1/annotated-source/nodes.html#section-60.

CoffeeScript treats constructor calls differently depending on whether they are called with a splat (`args...`) or without one.

Your code will give the desired result if you **either** invoke the extendObjectMaker with `new maker [2]...` **or** re-write your function as follows:

```
extendObjectMaker = (parent, Class) ->
  F = (anon...) -> Class.apply(@, anon)
  F:: = Object.create parent
  F::constructor = Class
  (args...) -> new F args...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is now dead

Comment: Updated! Note that this is relevant only for CoffeeScript 1.x - not sure how CoffeeScript 2 would treat different constructor calls.